# How to import Date fields from excel file into Oracle database table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, excel, import

I have an error while trying to import Date field from excel file to table in Oracle database.

```
Rapport d'erreur :
Erreur SQL : ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

SQL Developper transforms the date fields into `to_date(date_field)` in the sql request.

Comment: Can you please provide some additional data, such as the schema of the database table you're attempting to load, as well as some sample data from your excel file?

Comment: if a date column is the problem you might need to set your nls settings. in the database `show parameter nls_date_format` and to change issue `alter session / schema`. in plsql developer go to tools->preferences->database->nls->date format \ timestamp format. On the client side generaly it can be found in the registry under HKLM\Software\oracle\....

Comment: I set nls settings like that :
DD/MM/YYYY, by default it's was DD/MM/RR, but in both there an error while importing excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. In the window wizard for importing data from excel file, we can specity data format for each date field, it must be MM/DD/YYYY (I think this is the default  excel date format).